# Can you change the location of .qgis from the home directory to another folder on Windows in QGIS1.8?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to change the location of the .qgis folder to another location ( for example on a network drive H:\ ) in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

The command line option `--configpath` should do what you want, see:

http://documentation.qgis.org/html/en/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html

You can add it at the end of qgis.bat in the bin folder.